# Du shows wrong file size for about 1 minute

Tags: linux, du

I have a problem with `"du -hs"` showing a wrong file size for about 1 minute.
for example: downloading 200MB file, and checking with `du` right after the download has been completed will show 1.1MB. than after about 60 seconds it will show the correct size.

Comment: That sounds weird.. Unless the machine is still committing to disk when you 1st run du. Try running "sync;du -sh" ?  It might be that if you're downloading via a browser, it saves it to a temp file first of all then when completed, copies it to the correctly named file? Try doing an "ls -lrt" in the download directory to see which files are updated last (most recent at the end of the listing).

Comment: `sync;du -sh` helped, thanks! won't it hurt server performance?

Comment: negligibly - the server will do a sync every X seconds anyway.

Comment: If this solves your problem, post it as an answer.